# pytest recording results in addition to the pass/fail

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-2.7, pytest

I've just started using pytest. Is there any way to record results in addition to the pass/fail status?

For example, suppose I have a test function like this:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def server():
   # something goes here to setup the server

def test_foo(server):
   server.send_request()
   response = server.get_response()
   assert len(response) == 42
```

The test passes if the length of the response is 42. But I'd also like to record the response value as well ("...this call will be recorded for quality assurance purposes...."), even though I don't strictly require an exact value for the pass/fail criteria.

Comment: What do you want to do with the extra, logged data? E.g. do you want to be able to compare different test runs later on? It seems like the data you want to gather might be better off as a separate suite/thing (e.g. instrumentation/integration). If you don't need anything especially 'fun' then saving the data to flat files might be acceptable?

Comment: I just want a structured way to store any auxiliary data with each test. Yeah, I could do the out-of-band approach and store it myself... I was hoping pytest might provide a feature.

It would be for a human being to look at + just double-check that the test results looked reasonable.

Comment: I've not come across such a thing for any unit testing framework (not to say none exist). But given the broad nature if the data you want to store (and what you may want to use it for), you're probably better off rolling your own. Perhaps you could consider using an arrangement of test module loggers, all inheriting from a specialy-named parent with a handler that will log to a special file of your choosing?

Comment: Maybe you need something like this: `assert len(response) == 42, "My message"` but it will show only for fails

Answer (score 0):

## Use `print result,` then run `py.test -s`

`-s` tells py.test to not capture stdout and stdout.

Adapting your example:

```
# test_service.py
# ---------------

def test_request():
    # response = server.get_response()
    response = "{'some':'json'}"
    assert len(response) == 15
    print response, # comma prevents default newline
```

Running `py.test -s` produces

```bash
$ py.test -s test_service.py
=========================== test session starts ===========================
platform linux2 -- Python 2.7.6 -- py-1.4.26 -- pytest-2.6.4
collected 1 items 

test_service.py {'some':'json'}.

======================== 1 passed in 0.04 seconds =========================
$
```

### Or use python logging instead

```
# test_logging.py
# ---------------
import logging
logging.basicConfig(
    filename="logresults.txt", 
    format="%(filename)s:%(lineno)d:%(funcName)s %(message)s") 

def test_request():
    response = "{'some':'json'}"
    # print response, # comma prevents default newline
    logging.warn("{'some':'json'}") # sorry, newline unavoidable
    logging.warn("{'some':'other json'}")
```

Running `py.test` produces the machine readable file `logresults.txt`:

```
test_logging.py:11:test_request {'some':'json'}
test_logging.py:12:test_request {'some':'other json'}
```

### Pro tip

Run `vim logresults.txt +cbuffer` to load the logresults.txt as your quickfix list.

Comment: Seriously? I appreciate the suggestion, but printing is not something I would recommend for diagnostics in any language. What you suggest is OK for human readable report but would require screen-scraping techniques for machine parsing. I can use the python `logging` module if the test framework doesn't have a structured way to save auxiliary data.

Comment: Whoops. Missed the bit about being machine parsable. Pytest doesn't keep a database of results, make its test results available as a logger, or report test return values. Its channel for auxiliary test data is [standard out/err](http://pytest.org/latest/capture.html). There is a built in option for a machine readable report: `--junit-xml=report.xml`. That assumes a tool that handles junit-xml and the extra data gets sent to standard out or standard error.

Answer (score 0):

see my example of passing test data to ELK
http://fruch.github.io/blog/2014/10/30/ELK-is-fun/

later I've made it a bit like this:

```
def pytest_configure(config):
    # parameter to add analysis from tests teardowns, and etc.
    config.analysis = []

def pytest_unconfigure(config):
    # send config.analysis to where you want, i.e. file / DB / ELK
    send_to_elk(config.analysis)

def test_example():
   pytest.config.analysis += [ "My Data I want to keep" ]
```

this is per run/session data, and not per test (but I'm working on figuring out how to do it per test)

I'll try updating once I have a working example...